# AFNetworking upload image

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I'm trying to upload an image to my server from my iOS app, but the "Unsuccessful" in the php script keep tricking. What am i doing wrong?

The `Log` returns "`File = Unsuccessful`" and then then the binary file numbers.

iOS (Upload image):

```
-(IBAction)uploadPhoto:(id)sender{

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://SERVERURL"]];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage, 0.5);
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"message": self.descriptionView.text};
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [manager POST:@"rest.of.url" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        //do not put image inside parameters dictionary as I did, but append it!
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"file" fileName:@"upload.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);
   }];
    [op start];


        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    } 
}
```

PHP CODE:

```
<?
if(!empty($_POST)) 
{
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/pictures';
    $file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['upload.jpg']);
    $uploadfile = $directory . $file;
    var_dump($_FILES);
    $randomPhotoID = md5(rand() * time());
echo 'file='.$file;
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
       echo 'successful';

    }
    else
    {
    echo 'unsuccessful';

}
}
else
{
    echo('Empty post data');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget **/** at the end of your directory because you concatenate that with the filename:

```
$directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/pictures/';
```

if you still get issue try to add more checks:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST)) {
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']){
    //we got something, set it up
    $directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/pictures/';
    $file = basename( $_FILES['userfile']['name']);        
    $uploadfile = $directory . $file; 
    $randomPhotoID = md5(rand() * time());
    //perform the upload
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
      echo 'successful';
    } else {
      echo 'unsuccessful';
    }
  }else{
      echo "Nothing was uploaded";
  }
}else{
    echo 'POST is not set cannot proceed to upload';
}
```

Comment: Can you try hardcoding the directory path

Comment: i've hardcoded it and found a little error in the directory path and i'm sure its correct now, but does not solve the problem. The server is an ubuntu server, don't know if that can be a problem.

Comment: @user3423384 so what does the script echo? you have not mention that part

Comment: var/www/User/core/ios/pictures/